# Overriding default breakpoints in MUI System with typescript

Tags: material-ui, overriding, default, breakpoints

I am trying to set new breakpoints for my container width in MUI System.  It works without typescript, but in my typescript project, it does not recognize my custom breakpoints and only recognizes the default breakpoints (xs, sm, md, lg, and xl). I followed the suggested BreakpointOverrides suggested [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/)

````
    ```
    import React from 'react';
    import Container from '@mui/system/Container';
    import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/system';

    declare module '@mui/system' {
      interface BreakpointOverrides {
        // Your custom breakpoints
        laptop: true;
        tablet: true;
        mobile: true;
        desktop: true;
        xldesktop: true;
        // Remove default breakpoints
        xs: false;
        sm: false;
        md: false;
        lg: false;
        xl: false;
      }
    }

    const theme = createTheme({
      breakpoints: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        //@ts-ignore
        values: {
          mobile: 0,
          tablet: 640,
          laptop: 1024,
          desktop: 1280,
        },
      },
    });
    const HeroHomepage = ({}) => {
      return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Container
            sx={{
              bgcolor: {
                mobile: 'green',
                tablet: 'blue',
                laptop: 'orange',
                desktop: 'yellow',
              },
              width: 200,
              height: 500,
            }}
          >
            <div>hello world</div>
          </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
    };
    ```
````

When I do this, no color at all is applied to the container, as it does not recognize the custom breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest version of MUI. It seems to be recently fixed, according to this discussion https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/26369.

In my case it helped: no TS errors now and breakpoints works.